# How to save the data after making a request to an API with react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

How to save the data after making a request to an api with react native I want to save the information with asyncstorage so that it is available when in offline mode but I do not know how to do this. I need a example or something

Answer (score 0):

it's really simple, after fetching data from your API, you use [AsyncStorage](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html) as shown in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

Here is good example of AsyncStorage

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/react_native/react_native_asyncstorage.htm